# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord filter issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a problem.

**Problem description:**
I have table Projects and table Assets.
I need show Projects only where model_aseets is exists only.

**Example code**
My query:

```
select  s3_object_key,  a.id from projects
left join assets a on projects.id = a.project_id
where asset_category =2
```

```
projects = Project.where(Asset.ar_model.exists)
```

**Get an error:**

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
“exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `exists' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Could someone help, please.
Thanks

Comment: You didn't post a schema, how are assets and projects related ? Does a project have multiple assets? Can an asset belong to multiple projects?

Comment: Are you using Rails 3?